# Calculating distance between two closest points on graph in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, distance, network, proximity

I have a graph layer and a point layer. The points are snapped to the graph. I want to get the distance between the closest points on the graph

[image]

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

### Solution 1: Beeline distance

Use distance matrix tool for a quick and dirty solution: ignoring the network, just beeline distance (for using network, see below). At least from your screenshot, this should be more or less the same for the shortest distance.

Run Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>[Distance Matrix](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisdistancematrix)</kbd> and use the same layer for Input and Target point layer. Open the attribute table of the the resulting layer and sort the column `Distance` to get the shortest distance: `InputID` and `TargetID` shows you the point pair that has the smallest distance in between:

[image]

### Solution 2: Distance over network

To do the same, but using network distances, use the [plugin QNEAT3](https://root676.github.io/) and run  one of the [OD Matrix tools](https://root676.github.io/OdMatrixAlgs) like `OD-Matrix from Points as Table (n:n)`.